# What can be the reason for Blender 2.9+ not decoding Alpha channel in a video

Tags: transparency, video-sequence-editor, video

I'm having strange issue with Blender 2.9 and above (so 3.0 too), which is not happening for earlier versions. Video Sequence Editor has trouble working with .mp4 encoded using PNG video codec, containing an alpha channel. It's rendered in Blender 2.81. VSE either imports it with correct number of frames but without alpha channel or just as a 1 frame with an alpha channel. Compositor in the same versions of Blender don't have this issue. Imports and interprets the alpha channel correctly.
I'm working on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS GeForce GTX 1050 Ti and NVIDIA Driver Version:390.144.
Installed Python versions: 2.7.18 and 3.8.10
Anything that comes to your mind will be helpful cause I have no clue where to start looking.

Comment: Did you change the blending mode from Cross to Alpha Over?

Comment: Of course @joshsanfelici and if I wouldn't it still didn't explain importing just one frame instead of whole video in some cases.

Comment: mp4 does not support alpha.

Comment: @MartyFouts So how is that I can use .mp4 videos with alpha channel properly in earlier Blender versions and Open Shot both on Linux and Windows 10 and Blender 2.9+ reads it properly in Compositor?

Comment: [list of formats that support alpha](https://www.digitalrebellion.com/blog/posts/list_of_video_formats_supporting_alpha_channels)  You can import an mp4 and do a substitution to derive an alpha channel from a background color, but you have to output in a format that does support alpha.

Comment: @MartyFouts The thing is MPEG-4 (.mp4) according to this info: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/media/video_formats.html does support an alpha channel, and I'm using it in the software mentioned above without any trouble so...

Comment: Ah, the abomination of using MP4 as a container rather than a codec.  Sure, you can stick a codec that can support alpha into an MP4 container, but that's not an MP4 anymore, it's an abuse of terminology.  I'm surprised anytime it works.

Comment: @MartyFouts So if I can do that (use mp4 as a container), why I shouldn't and why it's an abomination in your opinion?

Comment: Don't mind me.  I've never been fond of the confusion that using "mp4 "to stand for both the codec and the container causes.  It leads to things like our exchange where I was mistakenly thinking you were talking about the codec, but you were talking about the container.